# heroku db:push - The MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to push my local development database up to heroku with `heroku db:push` but it's not connecting.  Anyone know what the problem is?

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps#import_push_to_heroku

```
$ heroku db:push --confirm spanish-day-111
Loaded Taps v0.3.23
Auto-detected local database: mysql://root@localhost/blog_development?encoding=utf8
Warning: Data in the app 'spanish-day-111' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.
Failed to connect to database:
  Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError -> Mysql::ClientError::ServerGoneError: The MySQL server has gone away
```

Comment: I faced it once, I had to redefine everything concerning my database using command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally figured out that I didn't have the mysql gem in my current rvm gemsite.

This fixed the problem for me.

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```